# I can not make a copy of all the files inside a folder with C ++

Tags: c++, windows, directory, dev-c++, file-copying

I wanted to write a program in C++ where it copied all the files in a folder and pasted them into another folder. For now, I managed only with a single file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CopyFile ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WinRAR\\Rar.txt","C:\\Users\\mypc\\Desktop\\don't touch\\project\\prova", TRUE);
```

Comment: `CopyFile()` only copies one file.   To copy multiple files, you need to loop over all files, and call `CopyFile()` for each one.   Look up the functions `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` for options to implement that loop, as well as `GetFileAttributes()` and `SetFileAttributes()` if you need to copy file properties (e.g. protections).   Bear in mind that, directories contain directories - to copy a directory, it is necessary to loop over all files in the directory - recursively.

Comment: Alternatively, like at `SHFileOperation()`, then you don't need a loop, you can use wildcards instead.

Comment: Check out [`std::filesystem::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy), which *should* work on any system, not just Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggest, CopyFile only copies one file at a time. One option is to loop through the directory and copy the files. Using filesystem (which can be read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem?view=vs-2017) ), allows us to recursively open directories, copy that directories files and the directories directories and on and on until everything has been copied. Also, I did not check the arguments being input by the user, so don't forget that if its important to you.

```
# include <string>
# include <filesystem> 

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
//namespace fs = std::filesystem; // my version of vs does not support this so used experimental

void rmvPath(string &, string &);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* verify input here*/

    string startingDir = argv[1]; // argv[1] is from dir
    string endDir = argv[2]; // argv[2] is to dir

    // create dir if doesn't exist
    fs::path dir = endDir;
    fs::create_directory(dir);

    // loop through directory
    for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(startingDir))
    {
        // convert path to string
        fs::path path = p.path();
        string pathString = path.string();

        // remove starting dir from path
        rmvPath(startingDir, pathString);

        // copy file
        fs::path newPath = endDir + pathString;
        fs::path oldPath = startingDir + pathString;


        try {
            // create file
            fs::copy_file(oldPath, newPath, fs::copy_options::overwrite_existing);
        }
        catch (fs::filesystem_error& e) {
            // create dir
            fs::create_directory(newPath);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


void rmvPath(string &startingPath, string &fullPath) 
{
    // look for starting path in the fullpath
    int index = fullPath.find(startingPath);

    if (index != string::npos)
    {
        fullPath = fullPath.erase(0, startingPath.length());
    }
}
```